# Show the stock for configurable Products MAGENTO

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Im trying to show on the frontend the stock when we have less than 5 products.

For simple products is easy but when we are talking about configurable products it is not working. 
This is the code I tried but is not working, the var $product is coming empty so I am always getting a 0 in $total_qty

Here is the code that I am using:

```
    $product=Mage::getModel("catalog/product");         
    $prod=$product->load($prod_id);
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($prod);
    $col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

    $total_qty=0;
    foreach($col as $sprod)
    {
    $sprod=$product->load($sprod->getId());
    $qty = intval(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($sprod)->getQty());
    $total_qty+=$qty;
    }
    ?>

    ---

    <p class="availability in-stock">
    <?php //echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span>
    <?php
    if (($__manStock >= 1) && ($__manStock < 5))
     {
     echo $this->__("¡ JUST $total_qty LEFT !");
     }

    ?>
</span></p>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configurable Products don't have stock. The simple products do.

You will have to query the associated products.

You can get the associated products using getAllowProducts()